# How to use template/format to print label from label printer in c#

Tags: c#

I am beginner to .NET programming. I am creating an windows application for printing label from Cognitive label printer.

Printer uses generic/text driver only. Here is the template format which I got from program manuals,

```
! 0 255 95 1                                                         
NOINDEX                                                              
PITCH 200                                                            
V PRESENTLABEL ON 220 220                                             
STRING 12X16 120 47 rtrimm 11-488515   51143   DBL   05/07/08   16:53
BARCODE CODE39WX- 120 40 140 5114311488515DBL                        
END
```

Right now, if I am not using this template then I can print Item number (just number no barcode), Item name and price on one label but by default I am getting two blank label on print. So, total three labels are utilize for one label print(1 Print + 2 Blank).

Can you suggest me how should I used this template?

I want to print say,

name, price and bar-code using this format/template or whether I should used this or not. I am not clear right now.

Seriously, I am spending hours on this to understand how should I print label in proper format from label printer.

Answer (score 0):

How is the printer connected to the computer?  Ethernet? Serial? USB? LPT? Bluetooth?

Data is normally sent to label printers directly via one of the above interfaces.

If you insist on going through a "driver" then you should use the Win32 API to send your commands directly to the printer.

This KB article presents a C# class to do exactly that: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=322091

Comment: Printer is connected to the computer through USB. I had gone through KB article initially but it doesn't work, it gives me unusual error. I had read the program manuals and it stated that printer doesn't required any API.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Anyone got the answer for this?